# Open local link from webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, cordova

I have a page in my PhoneGap webapp (file:///mypath/), that opens a webpage (http://www.example.com/) in my server. In this webpage I need to return after I do all my stuff in my webapp.

This is my webpage source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stile.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.7, user-scalable=no"> 
     <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <script src="JS/func.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->

    <title>BParty</title>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#e20a7e; overflow:none;">

         <img src="IMG/CIAMBELLA_03.png" class="icons5" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">
         <br>
         <br>
        <div align="center" style="color:#FFF;">
        <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
        <font style="font-size:5em;">OOPS!</font><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <font style="font-size:2.5em;">Sembra che tu non sia connesso</font><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <font style="font-size:1.5em;">A breve sarai reindirizzato</font>
        </tr>
        <br>
         <tr>
         <font style="font-size:1em;">Se non vuoi aspettare clicca 
         <a href="<? $location = $_GET['location']; echo $location ?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff" target="_blank">QUI</a></font>
        </tr>
       </table>
       </div>


      <?

        header( "refresh:5;url=$location" ); ?>




</body>
</html>
```

This is my localpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ourLocation = document.URL;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var goto = "<a href='http://www.bestparty.altervista.org/MIRKO/pag2.php?location=" + ourLocation + "'>dicjdb</a>";
document.write(goto);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stile.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.7, user-scalable=no"> 
     <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.1.js.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->
    <script src="JS/func.js"></script> <!--PER EVENTI-->

    <title>BParty</title>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#e20a7e; overflow:none;">
 <div id="navigation" style="overflow:none;">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr valign="bottom">
                                            <td valign="middle" width="25%" align="center">

                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="bottom" width="50%" align="center">
                                                <img src="IMG/LOGO-WHITE.png" class="logonbar" alt="DONUT"/>
                                            </td>
                             <td  width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
         <img src="IMG/CIAMBELLA_03.png" class="icons5" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">
         <br>
         <br>
        <div align="center" style="color:#FFF;">
        <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
        <font style="font-size:5em;">OOPS!</font><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <font style="font-size:2.5em;">Sembra che tu non sia connesso</font><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <font style="font-size:1.5em;">A breve sarai reindirizzato</font>
        </tr>
        <br>
         <tr>
         <font style="font-size:1em;">Se non vuoi aspettare clicca 
         <a href="<? $location = $_GET['location']; echo $location ?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff" target="_blank">QUI</a></font>
        </tr>
       </table>
       </div>




  <script>
      function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
        }

      </script>  
      <script>


        variable = getUrlVars()["location"];
            alert(variable);
       //window.location.href = variable;
       </script>




</body>
</html>
```

I added the js script to return at the local page on my app but it doesn't work, it stays on my php page on my server, same result by clicking the a href that contains the php

Comment: Your [PHP syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp) is invalid to start with, php should start with `<?php`. Just to start.

Comment: Read more w3schools, lol. `<?` is still a valid syntax, though some ini settings should be on.

Comment: lets say you have two pages ... you will go to the second page from the first one ,, but do you want to return some data from the second to the first or just return ???

Comment: i need to return some datas

Comment: i need to go from the local page to the server page then return to the local page with 2 GET variables  @MohammadAlabed

Comment: @Marcodevelopingcenter sorry but your code not clear for me and you have some syntax error ,, please explain us what you have in the first page ,, and how you will move to the second one (click button , JS, ....) then what you have in the second (form ,, only html without form ...) and how you like to return to the first one (click button, auto redirect ....) and from where this data will come to resend it to the first one

Comment: use inAppBrowser plugin

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shaun Loftin.

Anyway, you can embed a local webpage using a simple IFRAME.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/local_webpage.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: the php page has functions on it @Snake,  
i need to go from the local page to the server page then return to the local page with 2 GET variables

Comment: You question title is "Open local link from webpage", and your explanation is not fully clear. I cannot ask you to write it in italian (I'm italian too), so I have to ask you more clearness. Via PHP you can obtain the remote HTML with file_get_contents() or with cURL. If you only need two parameters, you can pass them via GET both in local and remote pages.

Comment: then, i've got a local page (file:///...) in html, in this page there's an a href that points to a php page on my server, this php file does the facebook login and save  the facebook id and the facebook username, then i need to return to my local page (file:///...) passing the FBID and the FBUSERNAME @Snake

Comment: If you are using the file:// protocol you can't pass any variables via GET. file:// simply read the text in your HTML file and can not interpret the PHP code. You need to install a local webserver like EasyPHP or WAMPP, and use http://localhost/local_webpage.php?FBID=xxx&FBUSERNAME=yyyy

Comment: the real problem is how to return from the www.mydomain.com/file.php to file:///mypath.file.html @Snake

Comment: You can return to your local page using a simple javascript redirect, window.location.href = "file://your_file.html?FBID=xxx&FBUSERNAME=yyyy".

Comment: why if i use header location in php passing the same url doesn't work? @Snake

Comment: Header in PHP can be used only if you have not already printed something in stdout, because headers haft to go before the body in the HTTP Protocol. Probably you tried to call Header() after printing some stuff.